# File transfer from one folder to another

Tags: powershell

I was wondering if anyone can help me with this problem, of moving files from `C:` drive to a network drive.

So at work we have a machine that outputs `.txt` files. For example these files include data about pets, so in the folder I have hundreds of files that are named similar to `dogs_123456_10062019.txt` then `cats_123457_10062019.txt`.

Now the first number is a reference number than changes per `.txt` file that is created and the other is a date, as said I can have hundreds of these per day the reference and date is not important to the transfer as the file includes all this information anyway

Now I have a network folder structure of `Y:dogs` & `Y:cats` and wanted a automated script that transfers all dog & cat text files to the corresponding network drive.

The network drive name cannot be changed as it's used by a monitoring software that outputs graphs based on the information in the text file.

Is this possible? Hopefully I've explained myself

Cheers

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? Ideally, you should provide a [MCVE] of what you've tried, and include specific information on how it failed, with error messages and/or erroneous output. [SO] is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [Ask] a Good Question.

Comment: Ah ok didnt realise

Comment: I'm learning rapidly I might come back to this as I pick up more info cheers

Comment: Right I have a script running and it's doing its job but I'd like to try and refine it a little

I have the following

while($true)
{$i++
    Write-Host “Transfering to ...”
    
$Files = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\..... "*.txt" -Recurse

foreach($File in $Files)
{
    if ($File.name -like "...*.txt")
    {
        Move-Item -Path $File.FullName "C:\...."
    }
    elseif ($File.name -like "...*.txt")
    {
        Move-Item -Path $File.FullName "C:\...."
    }
}
}

Comment: 2 problems with this are

1# it runs all the time, is there anyway to monitor the path folder and run script when .txt files hit the folder?

2# I'd like to backup the file in another location is there anyway I can send the files to 2 locations?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

If folder names match file names then you can do something like that:

```
$SourceFolderPath = "C:\Source\"  
$DestinationFolderPath = "Y:"  
$FileList = Get-ChildItem -Path $SourceFolderPath  

foreach($File in $FileList){  
    $FolderName = ($File.Name | Select-String -Pattern ".+?(?=_)").Matches.Value 
    $File | Move-Item -Destination "$DestinationFolderPath\$FolderName"  
}
```

If names of folders do not match file names, you would need to manually create a dictionary of what should go where and then translate those

The code above is obviously not an enterprise level stuff :)